Teams Back end Change of May 10, 2024 breaks screenshot sharing with Teams Apps/Bots - URL format has changed and no access to Bots
Microsoft appears to have rolled out a Teams Back end Change on May 10, 2024 which breaks screenshot sharing to Teams Apps/Bots.  We noticed a URL format change and the resulting URL provides no access to Bots.
When an end user on Teams pastes a screenshot to a Teams App (Bot) in a one-one chat (Personal Scope), Teams stores the screenshot as an image on smba.trafficmanager.net and send the URL to location to the Bot.  The bot can then use its authentication/bearer token and downloads the screen shot.
This has worked fine for 3+ years but a change rolled out on Fri May 10, 2024 first in Europe and then in Americas has broken bot access to the URL that points to the smba.trafficmanager.net location that stores the image.
Our devs analyzed the change and found that a tenantid is now inserted in the URL and the resulting URL no longer provides access to the bot to download the screenshot.  See snippet below (Error provided is API isnt enabled for the bot, and presents as a HTTP 405 error.

Note that if we strip out the tenantid from the new URL to match the old format, our bots are able to download the screenshot.   We have had to make an emergency workaround using regex to strip out the tenantid while we (and hopefully Microsoft) investigate this further.
The bot is built using Microsoft Bot Framework and is a multi-tenant bot.  Bot is deployed in the end user tenant using a manifest by the Teams Admin and part of a Global Permission Policy.  Additionally, it is not just one bot or tenant facing this issue.  We see this across multiple bot and multiple tenants with different instances of our application
This does not seem to affect 1-1 chats between end users - just between user and Teams App/Bot.  Also attachments shared via paperclip have a sharepoint URL and they are not impacted - just the cut and paste screenshots.
Questions

Any other devs seeing this?
Is there a different recommendation on how bots should download screenshots?
Any new permissions needed for bots for this specific action?  None were needed before May 10, 2024.


We are able to repro this issue. We are checking this with the engineering team and will get back to you.

An incident has been raised for this issue, we will keep you posted on the updates.

Microsoft has finally acknowledged this bug I reported above.  Hopefully the fix is to revert to the previous behavior, else ISVs will have to scramble again to roll out a different fix.

