‎Teams botbuilder inline attachment download stopped working‎
Describe the bug
On 5/10/24 we started receiving errors from Microsoft API when attempting to download inline attachments that we receive by bot builder sdk. This is impacting all of our apps. No changes were done from our side. Here is the example api:
Received payload by the bot:
{ "contentType": "image/*", "content": { "downloadUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/f5cedd40-cc83-4a78-8c26-3328f7ceea20/v3/attachments/0-wus-d7-c727ca4fc1e3d4f753a36db52ebc183a/views/original", "uniqueId": "da962cd8-1828-4d56-a5b0-bd1e4f36343e", "fileType": "png", "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkwxS2ZLRklfam5YYndXYzIyeFp4dzFzVUhIMCIsImtpZCI6IkwxS2ZLRklfam5YYndXYzIyeFp4dzFzVUhIMCJ9.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.ICOrwGAsSsSJtb4ieYRf2ZLYIgJ5SB_PpBoMA-YvQweTiitXROTwJaX6h-zp1QHQdvj30nCpSUaMtgysMqTscNm25j9tyU2zpj6nZdVm8XMhYKodNNZogQxxIwXT97eahVc61R9zVZQoM4Bz2Alf8tGjPa-zVIybcBZp1F9PeRnZsweQS9zPakO0Ps0AQWk01H2QVFMKEYSxvAv9mGHn1RLJOgmRqdeW3Lm-Uf0GY7Mn6OFV4ClVGAvbSstkXzRvzRT8g6CLpFdzYiccZbxEZmNfPDBFZGk_To1mVvkX7e4DbeNjoCnG2jQlvOaDznIkwZrA_7ntyExMWSjQ9e4_Zw" }, "contentUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/f5cedd40-cc83-4a78-8c26-3328f7ceea20/v3/attachments/0-wus-d7-c727ca4fc1e3d4f753a36db52ebc183a/views/original", "name": "attachment-1c1eef31-8d4d-4185-a9fd-056774c5ef09.png" }
Attempt to download as per this example: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/15.handling-attachments/bots/attachmentsBot.js#L83
GET https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/f5cedd40-cc83-4a78-8c26-3328f7ceea20/v3/attachments/0-wus-d7-c727ca4fc1e3d4f753a36db52ebc183a/views/original
Headers: Authorization: Bearer {{token from above payload}}
Error response: 405Method Not Allowed
{ "error": { "code": "BadArgument", "message": "API isn't enabled for the bot" } }
Tried to Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior locally:
Send inline message in teams to the bot (IGNORE THE MESSAGES ITS JUST A SCREENSHOT)

Expected behavior
We should be able to download the image with the given url and token as per example here
Screenshots from Postman

Versions
What package version of the SDK are you using. (botbuilder@4.16.0)
What nodejs version are you using (v16.20.2)
What os are you using (Mac)
Issue in GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/4666

Similar issue is reported here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78471448/teams-back-end-change-of-may-10-2024-breaks-screenshot-sharing-with-teams-apps. We are able to repro this issue. We are checking this with the engineering team and will get back to you.

An incident has been raised for this issue, we will keep you posted on the updates.
